# Shifting string character left and right with conditions

Tags: javascript

I need some help, I'm really new to this programming thing and I've been trying to complete a beginner challenge here and there, mostly from my friends tho, so I got a problem and its almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152391/shift-strings-circular-left-and-right).

except my string = `abcdXYZefgXYZhij`, with condition that text "XYZ" can't be shifted, so basically i need to shift the lowercase character only.

Here's the desired output if `leftShifts=6, rightShifts=0`

```
efXYZghijXYZabcd
```

Here's the code that i get from the link

```
function getShiftedString(s, leftShifts, rightShifts) {
  const arr = Array.from(s);
  console.log(arr);
  const netLeftShifts = (leftShifts - rightShifts) % arr.length;
  return [...arr.slice(netLeftShifts), ...arr.slice(0, netLeftShifts)]
    .join('');
}
console.log(getShiftedString(s, leftShifts, rightShifts));
```

Here's the result from code above

```
ZefgXYZhijabcdXY
```

As you can see the XYZ is shifted together with the lowercase, do i need to split it and join them again? Please help and guide me if there's anyway to do it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas hello i already edited it, could you please check if its good enough to be opened again? thanks

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this on your own? And as a beginner I would start with a script as simple as possible - which would be a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition before slicing:

```
if(str[0].match('[a-z]'))
```

it will only return null if your item doesn't match to the pattern which is a set of lower case alphabets.